# karma: Firefox default location

Tags: firefox, karma-runner

Where karma firefox launcher expects firefox to be by default? When I run my karma tests it picks up Chrome and IE in their respective default locations - I do not even know what they are, but for firefox I have to explicitly set up the FIRFOX_BIN variable. I am running Win7 and the firefox is installed in its default location: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firefox launcher doesn't take into account 64 bit Windows. There are currently [3 pull requests](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-firefox-launcher/pulls) to fix this, but none have been accepted.

The Chrome launcher also has the same issue, but you must have it installed in the AppData folder of your profile, which is the first place the Chrome launcher checks.